# Validating student ID starting with specific prefix

Tags: regex, laravel

Until now, I have been validating the ID with the following regex:

```
's_id' => 'unique:users|required|max:255|regex:/^\d{3}\-\d{2}\-\d{3}$/'
```

It validates the ID in the `***-**-***` format.

How can I validate the students id having the initial of `131-35-***` only?

Comment: So, what is the problem? Use `regex:/^131-35-\d{3}$/` if the first 5 digits are known.

Comment: wow!!! I am so dumb.

Comment: Thank you so much, Sir @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Please also consider also [upvoting the answer(s) that turned out useful for you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `\d{3}` matches any three digits and `\d{2}` matches any two digits, your current regex just matches any first 5 digits.

If the digits are set, known beforehand, they can be "hard-coded" into the pattern.

Use

```
regex:/^131-35-\d{3}$/
```

Now, only the last 3 digits can be any digits from `0` to `9`.